# Scene freezes on particular action

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm beginner in cocos2d. I have different sprites, that each of them run some action, and animate. But I noticed, that when I'm trying to have some logic in Sequence of Actions, using `CCCalfFunc` and do some logic (change animation, position, etc.. ), it's freezing all actions on a screen for about a second. I guess it's blocking main thread but I wonder why it not decreasing frame rate?

It's still 60 fps, but whenever I run that action and do logic, it keeps blocking for a second. **My understanding was, that at worse scenario it would decrease frame rate, not freeze screen with actions.** So what solution can be in this case? I don't want to use `NSOperation`, GDC, because I'm updating sprites animations, positions, etc...

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us the code? Do you put all your update GUI code into the CCCalfFunc block?

Comment: @MrBonjour code is pretty big, I'm not at home now, will post later. But mostly yes, it's updating GUI state , of like 15 Sprites.Is it nor proper way update GUI in CCCallFunc block? I'm not using schedulers, because I need to update only once, or when something triggers (can be touch,etc..)

Comment: If you try to change sprite image, get news animation, and there are not in cache, or if you try to compute some hard algorithm into the callBack, then yes, the main thread will wait that the CCCalfFunc return, this is why this is actually freezing. You can calculate / browsing your image in another thread, then when it's done, you can re-assign it to your sprite.

Comment: @MrBonjour I think my problem is that I'm creating new animations, that are not in cache. Because I don't have very hard algorithm that can block main thread. Never thought that making Animation will block main thread, so I guess, I should cache them on initialize.

Comment: @MrBonjour So I'm still confused, why it's not dropping frame rate, and just freezes? When frame rate can be dropped down?

Comment: a programme "freeze" when it needs to finish one intensively huge instruction before accessing the next instruction. A programme slow down when there's lot of computation, but where it can reach lot of loop cycle in a interval. That's what is happening into your code: when you put animation into the cache, you're actually calculating all the sprite data into the main thread, and the programme can't execute the next instruction as long as this step is not done, so the openGl loop is not reached. And it slows down when you made lot of calculation into your openGl loop, but it still can render

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @MrBonjour  mentioned, my problem was that I was loading animations that are not in cache, using main thread. Using GCD solved my problem.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),^{
      //Load animations here
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
       //Update UI, change frames, run animations,etc...
    });
});
```